# simple question on C

Tags: c++, c, comparison, ascii

I have this snippet of the code

```
char    *str = “123”;
if(str[0] == 1) printf("Hello\n");
```

why I can't receive my `Hello` thanks in advance!
how exactly compiler does this comparison `if(str[0] == 1)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
if (str[0] == '1') ...
```

The difference is that you are comparing `str[0]` to the *number* 1, while my code above is comparing `str[0]` to the *character* `'1'` (which has ASCII value 49). Not all programming languages treat characters and numbers interchangeably in this way, but C does.

Check out [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for more information about how computers map numbers to characters.

Answer (score 8):

First the right way is to do this:

```
if(str[0] == '1')
```

Or :

```
if(str[0] == 49)
```

Second, you must take care of the difference between `1` and `'1'`

- `1` is a integer value...
- `'1'` is a character whose [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) equals 49

Which means:
`('1'==1)` is false !!

However `('1'==49)` is true !!

When you write `'1'` in C/C++ it -automatically- be translated to the corresponding [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `49`, that is how `'1'` is actually represented in C/C++

Comment: how exactly compiler does this comparison?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are comparing the first character of `str` to the number 1. The actual character code of `'1'` is 49. So, either of these will work:

```
if (str[0] == '1')

if (str[0] == 49)
```

Remember that `1` isn't the same as `'1'`. The first one is a number, the second one is a character. If you want to learn more about this, you should probably look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Answer (score 2):

*str is a pointer type char var...that store the base address of string .str[0] holds the first char ...that is 1 and also it is a char ..so,i it is denoted with is '1'...

try this :

```
if(str[0] == '1')
    printf("Hello \n");
```

Answer (score 1):

you're comparing a char to an int, it should be

```
if(str[0] == '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to ask

*str = “123”; if(str[0] == '1') printf("Hello\n");

See those single quotes around 1? You ned to compare a character and you are comparing an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if(str[0] == '1')` instead of comparing with `1` what means one and true in C :)

Answer (score 1):

use this ==>

```
if(str[0] == '1')
    printf("Hello \n");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one .....

```
if(str[0] == '1')
    printf("Hello \n");
```